# Overlapping dates in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table listing all of the times that a patient has received any type of medication that looks something like this:

```
Pat ID  Type of Admin    Order ID     Start Date          End Date
1       Medication       1            01/01/2016 04:20    01/04/2016 05:30
1       Medication       2            01/03/2016 18:30    01/07/2016 10:15
```

I would like to know the exact overlapping date ranges. So a resultant table would look like this:

```
Pat ID      First_Overlap      Last_Overlap
1           01/03/2016 18:30   01/04/2016 05:30
```

I am using Netezza. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How many medications need to be overlapping?  Or you just looking for periods when some had at least two medications?

Comment: Just any period with at least two meds overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Netezza however if I was to do this in MySQL or another SQL variant I would do something like this:

```
SELECT C.PatID AS PatID, MAX(C.FirstOverlap) AS FirstOverlap, MIN(C.LastOverlap) As LastOverlap
FROM (
  SELECT A.PatID AS PatID, CASE WHEN B.StartDate <= A.EndDate THEN B.StartDate ELSE A.EndDate END AS FirstOverlap,
  CASE WHEN B.EndDate >= A.StartDate THEN B.EndDate ELSE A.StartDate END AS LastOverlap
  FROM careAdmin AS A LEFT JOIN careAdmin AS B ON A.PatID = B.PatID AND A.OrderID = B.OrderID
  WHERE NOT B.EndDate <= A.StartDate OR B.StartDate >= A.EndDate
  ) C
GROUP BY C.PatID
```

Even though the syntax may differ slightly hopefully the process will help you get to the right answer.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you mean a.OrderID <> b.OrderID? This looks like it might account for the second order potentially ending for the first, though I'm a but confused as to why the a.End_Date would make the "first" overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I did mean to join the order id's as well as we are joining two copies of the same table together and this ensures that both the order id and patient id match to form the join. We are checking if A ends before B starts, if it doesn't and A ends after B starts then there is an overlap. Similarly if A starts before B ends then there is also an overlap. Hope this makes sense if not let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: This works well for two dates, though the first_overlap and last_overlap dates should be switched. It isn't quite right for multiple dates (so, if someone has 3 medication dates that overlap), but this piece of code really got me thinking in the right direction so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create temp table overlapTemp (
pat_id Int,
type_of_admin varchar(100),
order_id int,
start_dt timestamp,
end_dt timestamp
)
distribute on random;

insert into overlapTemp values(1,'Medication',1,'01/01/2016 04:20','01/04/2016 05:30');
insert into overlapTemp values(1,'Medication',2,'01/03/2016 18:30','01/07/2016 10:15');



select a.pat_id
,case when (b.start_dt,b.end_dt) overlaps (a.start_dt,a.end_dt) then b.start_dt end as overlap_start
,case when (b.start_dt,b.end_dt) overlaps (a.start_dt,a.end_dt) then a.end_dt end as overlap_end
from overlapTemp a inner join
overlapTemp b
on a.pat_id = b.pat_id
and a.order_id<b.order_id
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, thanks! Is the a.order_id < b.order_id to make sure that table "b" is always using the more recent start date? Can I also use b.start_st > a.start_dt? What about when the "second" medication order ends before the first one? Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: That is just to prevent doubling the cross join.  If you take it out and run it you will see the reason.